Wrapping image with text. RichText and Wrap do not work
What I want:
I would like to wrap some text around an image in Flutter. Since there are already many questions about that, what I mean by "wrapping some text around an image" is this:

To achieve that, I've tried using both RichText and Wrap classes, without success. What I'm getting with:
RichText (Text.rich) [not what I want]:

Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Wrap Image with text using Rich Text (Text.rich) test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                children: <InlineSpan>[
                  WidgetSpan(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text:
                        "loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum",
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

I've also tried adding alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle to WidgetSpan in the code above, getting the following result (also, not what I want):

Wrap [not what I want]:

Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Wrap Image with text using Wrap test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                Image.network(
                  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                ),
                Text(
                  "loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum",
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

How can I achieve what I want in Flutter?

Could you check this https://pub.dev/packages/drop_cap_text

There’s an old package called drop_cap_text that does exactly what you need, allowing you to wrap text around an image. However, it hasn't been updated to be compatible with newer versions of Flutter. Fortunately, you can use this fork of the package until the changes are merged into the original package.
For that, add the following to your pubspec.yaml file to include the updated package:
dependencies:
  drop_cap_text:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:parlough/drop_cap_text.git
      ref: feat/adapt-for-deprecations

After that, you can use the package like this:
DropCapText(
  'loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum loreum ipsum',
  dropCapPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8, bottom: 8), // Padding between the text and the image
  dropCap: DropCap(
    width: 200, // Set the width of the image
    height: 200, // Set the height of the image
    child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
  ),
)



Thanks! It worked. Just a little detail I had to change on pubspec.yaml: using the git url: url: git@github.com:parlough/drop_cap_text.git caused an error of permission denied (publickey) when running flutter pub get. I changed the git url to: url: https://github.com/parlough/drop_cap_text.gitand it worked fine.

The Stack widget allows you to overlay widgets on top of each other. By strategically positioning the text and image, you can create a layout where the text wraps around the image.
Use the Positioned widget to place the image within the Stack, and then add padding to the text to ensure it wraps around the image.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Text Wrap Around Image')),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 210.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. '
                      'Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. '
                      'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://picsum.photos/100?image=9',
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I hope this may resolve your issue,

Please explain how this addresses the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

Okay check it out now
